# How to run Both the networking operations and loop operations together in android programming

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

package com.ravi.seggerclient;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    EditText text,text2;
    String selectedImagePath,ll=null;
    Timer ravi;
    static DatagramSocket clsoc;
    static InetAddress ip;
    static File ff;
    byte[] arr = null;
    static int len,totpac;
    static RandomAccessFile raf;
    static FileChannel chan;
    static int buffsize;
    static int i=0,id=0,numRead=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    final  String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1))
        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) 
                    {
                        String  root =                           Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                        selectedImagePath = root +"/Nenjodu.mp4";                                ff = new File(selectedImagePath);

                        text.setText(selectedImagePath+"File Is Found"+"File length"+ff.length());
                    }
                }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                text.setText(""+e);
            }
            }
    });

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button2))
    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
         public void onClick(View arg0)
         {

        try
        {

        Ravii rav = new Ravii();
        ll="NOT SENT";
        ll = rav.execute().get();
        text2.setText(""+ll);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Error in Sending",""+e);
        }


            }

       });

}



private class Ravii extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{

            clsoc = new DatagramSocket();
            ip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.137.1");
                len = (int)ff.length();
                totpac = len/(30*1024)+1;

                buffsize = 30;
                String ss ="#"+totpac+"&";

                Log.d("No of Packets",""+totpac);
                byte[] fsize = new byte[1024];
                fsize = ss.getBytes();


                DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(fsize,fsize.length,ip,8000);
            clsoc.send(dp);
            raf = new RandomAccessFile(ff,"rw");
                chan = raf.getChannel();
                while(numRead>=0)
                {
                    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024*buffsize);
                    if(i==id)
                    numRead = chan.read(buf);
                    if((numRead>0)&&(i==id))
                    {
                        arr = new byte[numRead];
                        System.arraycopy(buf.array(),0,arr,0,numRead);
                        DatagramPacket sp = new DatagramPacket(arr,arr.length,ip,8000);
                        clsoc.send(sp);
                        i++;
                        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
                        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                        clsoc.receive(receivePacket);
                        String mod = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                        System.out.println("\n" + mod);
                        id=Integer.parseInt(mod.substring(mod.indexOf("#") + 1, mod.indexOf("&")));

                    }
                    else if((numRead>0)&&(i!=id))
                    {
                        i--;

                        DatagramPacket sp = new DatagramPacket(arr,arr.length,ip,8000);
                        clsoc.send(sp);
                        text2.setText("ReSent "+i+" packet");
                        i++;
                        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
                        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                        clsoc.receive(receivePacket);
                        String mod = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                        id=Integer.parseInt(mod.substring(mod.indexOf("#") + 1, mod.indexOf("&")));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing to Send" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                return "SuccessFul";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        Log.d("Exception in the Client Sending",""+e);

           }

         }
    }
}
```

Hi i am new to Android Programming.This is my Code,Client side  to send a large file from one mobile to other using UDP protocol.Although UDP is not preferred for this works.It is a part of my project.Here when i started Networking in Android,i came to know that networks are done using Background threads in Android using AsyncTask but when i want to run loop for long time in background thread,loop includes networking(that is the reason Asynctask is preferred),i am facing an error 
Android Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare().
How to overcome this and how to run the networking and loop operations in Android programming together. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)

Avoid AsyncTask for your long blocking networking operating. Rather use basic Thread

private class Ravii extends Thread {

```
public void run() {
    try {

        clsoc = new DatagramSocket();
        ip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.137.1");
        len = (int) ff.length();
        totpac = len / (30 * 1024) + 1;

        buffsize = 30;
        String ss = "#" + totpac + "&";

        Log.d("No of Packets", "" + totpac);
        byte[] fsize = new byte[1024];
        fsize = ss.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(fsize, fsize.length, ip,
                8000);
        clsoc.send(dp);
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(ff, "rw");
        chan = raf.getChannel();
        while (numRead >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * buffsize);
            if (i == id)
                numRead = chan.read(buf);
            if ((numRead > 0) && (i == id)) {
                arr = new byte[numRead];
                System.arraycopy(buf.array(), 0, arr, 0, numRead);
                DatagramPacket sp = new DatagramPacket(arr, arr.length, ip,
                        8000);
                clsoc.send(sp);
                i++;
                byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(
                        receiveData, receiveData.length);
                clsoc.receive(receivePacket);
                String mod = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                System.out.println("\n" + mod);
                id = Integer.parseInt(mod.substring(mod.indexOf("#") + 1,
                        mod.indexOf("&")));

            } else if ((numRead > 0) && (i != id)) {
                i--;

                DatagramPacket sp = new DatagramPacket(arr, arr.length, ip,
                        8000);
                clsoc.send(sp);
                text2.setText("ReSent " + i + " packet");
                i++;
                byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(
                        receiveData, receiveData.length);
                clsoc.receive(receivePacket);
                String mod = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                id = Integer.parseInt(mod.substring(mod.indexOf("#") + 1,
                        mod.indexOf("&")));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing to Send",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        return "SuccessFul";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception in the Client Sending", "" + e);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: to java seeker,As per my knowledge  In Android versions above 3.0, Networking operations are blocked in main UI threads without any permissions. I preffered Asynctask for Networking,as it is a background thread

Comment: yes if you do network operation in main ui thread it will block the main ui. you have used asynctask, but asynctask is not allowed for long blocking operation. see official documentation on it.